# AnyLogic -- How run production line 15 hours per day & machine show malfunctioning 3 times in 10 days?

Tags: simulation, anylogic

**Part one:**

How can I run a production line only for 15 hours per day?

***My logic***
[image]

**Part Two:**

How to implement a machine malfunctioning 3 times in 10 days?
I achieved the malfunctioning of a machine using this logic.

```
if(countAssembler==10){
self.suspend(agent);
create_MyDynamicEvent(2, HOUR,agent);
}
```

But malfunctioning is occurring on item count (i.e. `countAssembler==10`) right now. **I want it to occur after 3 days.**

Answer (score 0):

part 1
To make the services work for a period of time every day, you need resources to be used in those services, and the resources to be subjected to a schedule. The schedule is an object that you can find in the process modeling library and there's a ton of documentation and examples on how to use them. Review the help documentation.

part 2
There's a block in the process modeling library called downtime. Again there's a ton of documentation and examples on how to use this for any model. Then you don't need any java code